# When should I use brackets with imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have two file, the first one is todoHelper.js

it has `export const addTodo = (list, item) => [...list, item]`

later on I want to use `addTodo` in another file, I simply do `import {addTodo} from './todoHelpers'`

But I'm also seeing people doing export default instead of just export. What's the differences?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have only one export default per file and hence when you do export default like

```
export default AddTodo = (list, item) => [...list, item]
```

You can import it like

```
import MyAddTodo from './todoHelpers'
```

Since babel knows that you are trying to access the default component, you can access it in you file by any name

Now suppose you do

```
export const AddTodo = (list, item) => [...list, item]
```

You can have multiple such exports in you file like

```js
export const AddTodo = (list, item) => [...list, item]  
export const DeleteTodo = (list, item) => [...list, item]
```

and when you import you will need to destructure them like

```
import {AddTodo, DeleteTodo} from './todoHelpers'
```

Now since you have multiple such exports thus babel wont know which component you are tyring to access if you access if by a different name like

```
import {MyAddTodo, MyDeleteTodo} from './todoHelpers'
```

If you want to do this you will have to import them as it is and them change thier name like

```
import {AddTodo as MyAddTodo, DeleteTodo as MyDeleteTodo} from './todoHelpers'
```

So as general practice you will `default export` the main component and the rest you can have as export normally or when you have only one component that you need to export from a file then you can choose whatever you want but a nice way will be to `export` it as default.

Comment: when to use export default? when u have 1 export?

Comment: Yes you can use it when you have one export. Although its up to you, the restriction is that you can have only one default export per file

Comment: the benefit of using default is that when other file import it it doesn't require the `{}`,correct? that's so little benefit haha.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Using default keyword with export gives us the liberty to import with alias name

```
export default k // in file my.js
```

can be imported with alias name 'b'

```
import b from 'my.js'
```