# ReactJs CreateClass is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports=React.createClass({
   render:function(){
   return(
        <div>
           <h1> the list  </h1>
        </div>   
   )}
})
```

When I run the above code I get the following error :

```
app.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: React.createClass is not a function
```

Is this because of a version difference or a typo ?

```
package.json-I have included create-react-class as seen here but not in the bower.json file 


 {
    "dependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
        "browserify": "^14.4.0",
        "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
        "ejs": "^2.5.7",
        "express": "^4.16.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-live-server": "0.0.31",
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "reactify": "^1.1.1",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
      }
    }
```

gulpfile.js -Am I missing some dependency in this file

```
var gulp= require('gulp');
var LiveServer= require('gulp-live-server');
var browserSync=require('browser-sync');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify= require('reactify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('live-server', function(){

    var server= new LiveServer('server/main.js');
    server.start();
})

gulp.task('bundle',function(){
  return browserify({
    entries:'app/main.jsx',
    debug:true,
  })
  .transform(reactify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp'))

})


gulp.task('serve',['bundle','live-server'],function(){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        proxy: "http://localhost:7777",
        port:9001
    })
})
```

And my main.jsx has the following

```
 var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var GroceryItemList=require('./components/GroceryItemsList.jsx');

React.render(<GroceryItemList/>,app);
```

the groceryitems.jsx has the following

```
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
module.exports=React.createReactClass({

        render:function(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1> Grocery Listify </h1>
                </div>

            )

        }
})
```

When I add the createReactClass I get an error: createReactClass is not a function and when I add import and ES6 syntax I get 'illegal import deceleration '
Thank you,

Naveen

Comment: Wouldn't there be a problem by trying to export an unnamed React component? btw, you should probably go with the updated and very well supported ES6 class syntax in the future.

Comment: I did that and I ended up with my browser totally frozen ...  strange ...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Per the [documents](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html), you need to get the npm create react class package. From the command line of your project's file path, you need to do `npm install create-react-class --save`, and then modify the code like this:

```
var React = require('react');
//You need this npm package to do createReactClass
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

    module.exports=createReactClass({
            render:function(){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h1> the list  </h1>
                    </div>   
                )
            }
```

You also need React DOM to render the components like this:

```
npm install react react-dom
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
ReactDOM.render(<GroceryItemList/>,app);
```

Comment: I get this error on the console 'createReactClass' is not a function

Comment: Did you do "npm install create-react-class --save" from the command line to install the package?

Comment: if we use module.exports=createReactClass it wont give the error createReactClass' is not a function

Comment: I still get an error ... basically in the console I get something like the function, let's say: Greeter, hasn't being declared ... strange ...

Comment: I got the same error, but after `npm install create-react-class`, I now get an error on the server side ```node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:259
  var components = content.split(".");
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.decode (.../project/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:259:28)
    at Namespace.io.sockets.on.socket (.../project/server.js:62:27)
...[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...``` I dont understand what is going on. This happens no matter how I do it.

Comment: yeah this was the best answer BY FAR

Answer (score 74):

This is surely a version problem, If you are starting fresh, I would suggest you to create a `React component` by extending `React.Component` rather than using `React.createClass` since its deprecated from version `16.0` onwards and has been moved to a separate package `'create-react-class'` as @Dream_Cap also mention

Also go with the ES6 syntax for imports. You would modify your code to

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
       return(
           <div>
               <h1> the list  </h1>
           </div>   
        )
     }
}
```

Comment: I get this when I try Import

 Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration while parsing file:

Comment: try "const React = require('react')"

Comment: Excellent answer! But when I kept the `default` it was throwing error: `...does not contain an export named ...`. Then I used `export class ...` without the `default`. Can you help me understand the need of `default` here?

Comment: @arsho, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051886/default-keyword-in-import-export-es6/42051990#42051990

Answer (score 22):

If you're getting an Error stating that `React.creatClass` is an undefined function it's because the newer versions of React don't support that.

You can try the below steps.

Install the `create-react-class` npm package:

```
npm install --save-dev create-react-class
```

Then create a new variable under the `ReactDom` variable:

```
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
```

Now instead of using `React.createClass()` for the components use the `createReactClass()` var.

Example:
Replace this:

```
var TodoComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(`<h1>`Helloooo`</h1>`);
    }
});
```

With this:

```
var TodoComponent = createReactClass({
    render: function() {
        return(`<h1>`Helloooo`</h1>`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi having same problem but now I'm facing `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help .This is how the final answer looks like:
1) use react-dom to render

```
 var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  var List=require('./components/List.jsx');
  ReactDOM.render(<List/>,app);
```

2) use create-react-class (not  react)  and export it '`module.exports= createReactClass({`.... instead of `module.exports=React.createReactClass` (this gives an error 'createReactClass' is not a function

Thank you all again!
'

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App = function(){};
App.prototype = Object.create(Component.prototype);
App.prototype.render = function(){
     return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
     )
   }
export default App;
```

In this way you could avoid Class keyword

Answer (score 0):

React.createClass is not listed in updated documentation, You have to go for createComponent with ECMA6 Class

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install first it could be that your devependencies in package.json is not fully installed.