# "Uncaught TypeError: React.createClass is not a function" in Render.js file (electron app)

Tags: javascript, electron, jsx, package.json, react-dom

I'm new to react.js and I am trying to get this code to replace one line in  an html file inside an electron app with whatever is in return inside the MainInterface variable

This is my Render.js File

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

//var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var MainInterface = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <h1>SUCCESSSSSSSSSSS</h1>
  );
}//render
});//MainInterface

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainInterface />,
  document.getElementById('projects')
);//render
```

This is the html file (looking to replace WPM ... loading) (I do have the last html tag that is missing here in my actual file)

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang ="en">   <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
>     <title>Project Manager</title>   </head>   <body>   <div claa="main">
>     <div class="page" id="projectratings">
>       <div id="projects">
>         <h2>WPM ... loading</h2>
>       </div>
>     </div>   </div> <script src="js/render.js"></script>   </body>
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ETest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app/main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "electron": "^1.7.8",
    "electron-packager": "^9.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "electron-reload": "^1.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  }
}
```

I have tried installing creat-react-class and using that (as seen in the line that is commented out in the render.js file)

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both react and react-dom

not sure what else I am missing

just keep getting

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\ElectronTesting\process\js\fake_6052bf8b.js:8 
Uncaught TypeError: React.createClass is not a function
```

my render.js file is found at  ElectronTesting\process\js\render.js 
not sure why it points to fake_6052bf8b.js I've been assuming that's some type of temp file (please correct me if I am wrong)

Thanks for any and all help.

**EDIT yep just a simple mistake, forgot to replace React.createClass  with createReactClass, thanks for the code example that made me finally see it!!

Comment: What error did you get when you tried to use `createReactClass`?

Comment: Is this new code? If so, don't use `create-react-class`, just write modern JS and extend your component from React's `Component` class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

React removed `createClass` from version 16. 
You can use `create-react-class` to migrate easily as shown in react documentation.

```
// Before (15.4 and below)
var React = require('react');

var Component = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MixinA],
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
});

// After (15.5)
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Component = createReactClass({
  mixins: [MixinA],
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
});
```

read more about this https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass

Comment: Thanks, while I had found this when I tried to implement it it seems that I forgot to replace React.createClass with createReactClass... in conclusion facepalm. thanks for the help!!

Comment: Also note that Mixins were deprecated quite a while ago because they were [a considered harmful pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html), so at this point you should really be thinking of switching to the current React way, rather than trying to maintain old patterns that are not *quite* old enough to be impossible to fairly easily replace. The longer you wait, the harder you're making it for yourself.

Comment: @Felipe no, they're the same

Answer (score 3):

```js
export default class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
           <h1>its works</h1>
        );
    }
};
```

this works for me, checkout this [ReactJs CreateClass is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482433/reactjs-createclass-is-not-a-function/46508616) thus its by exports React.component instead of using React.createClass

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of React, you will notice that React.createClass was removed from the library. One of the biggest changes is that you can create React components using JavaScript classes.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?