# TypeError: default.a.createClass is not a function in React v16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

sday.js

```
import React from 'react';

const sday= React.createClass({
  render( ){
    return (
      <div>hello world</div>
    );
  }
})
export default sday;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {sday} from  './Component/example';

window.React= React;

ReactDOM.render(<sday/> , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I am trying to render `sday` but I am getting an error of create class is not a function:

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createClass is not a function

Comment: What version of React are you using? `createClass` got removed in React 16.

Comment: i am using v-16.4.0 thank you for the information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJs CreateClass is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482433/reactjs-createclass-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 5):

[`createClass` got removed in React 16](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed-deprecations), which is why you get the error.

If you would still like to use `createClass`, you can use the standalone [create-react-class](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class) package.