# How to properly do alias for import in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have basic react class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Children extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Children</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default Children;
```

Which is located at `/scenes/Stash/Children/Children`. I want to `import` it like `StashChildren`.

```
import {Children as StashChildren} from './scenes/Stash/Children/Children';
```

But I get:

> 45:88-101 "export 'Children' (imported as 'StashChildren') was not
>   found in '_/scenes/Stash/Children/Children'

If I do just:

```
import {Children} from './scenes/Stash/Children/Children';
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: Can you upload an example of that 'Children'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the default export by either

`import StashChildren from './scenes/Stash/Children/Children'`

or

`import {default as StashChildren} from './Children';`

You just need to import the default under the name that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have exported children component as a default export you can import it by any name. So you simply need

```
import StashChildren from './scenes/Stash/Children/Children';
```

Check this [When should I use brackets with imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051886/when-should-i-use-brackets-with-imports/42051990#42051990) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Since you're exporting default you can call like 
`import StashChildren from './scenes/Stash/Children/Children';`

For alias, just remove the brackets:

`import Children as StashChildren from './scenes/Stash/Children/Children';`