# Why is my export const function not importing properly?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm creating a simple react app that export a file that contains a function that returns an array of objects:

```
export const listStudents = () => {
    return [{name:"Ljuben", lastName:"Angelkoski", indeks:"161161", nasoka:"KNI"},
            {name:"Pere", lastName:"Anastasov", indeks:"17350", nasoka:"PET"},
            {name:"Filip", lastName:"Shabanoski", indeks:"173521", nasoka:"PET"},
            {name:"Martin", lastName:"Krsteski", indeks:"163544", nasoka:"KNI"},
            {name:"Nikola", lastName:"Nacevski", indeks:"154874", nasoka:"ASI"}]; // replace the empty array with actual array with at least 5 student objects
}
```

And in my main component I have this code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import listStudents from './repository/studentRepository.js'

class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            students: listStudents
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <h2></h2>
        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

However when I run the app it gives me this error :

```
./src/Main.js
Attempted import error: './repository/studentRepository.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'listStudents').
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: You need to properly `import` your `studentRepository.js`

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use brackets with imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051886/when-should-i-use-brackets-with-imports/42051990#42051990)

Comment: Also change this.state={
            students: listStudents
        } to this.state={
            students: listStudents()
        }

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

`listStudents` is a named export, so you must import it like this:

```js
import { listStudents } from './repository/studentRepository.js'
```

If you don't want to change the import, you can use the default export for the function instead.

```js
export default () => {
    return [/* ... */]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mention default export in `children.js` ,so you need to import with name.

```
import { liststudents } from './children';
```

Or you have to mention default export in children like

```
export default const list = []
```

and also its a function in `children.js` .so to get data from it, you need to call it like.

```
 this.state = {
    students: listStudents()
 }
```

simpler way would be defined them as array like

```
export const listStudents = [...students arr]
```