# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function` Error using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am Trying to use **react-router-dom**. When I export my component as

```
class RandomComponent { // component code}
export default RandomComponent;
```

and use this as a component in Route as following -

```
<Route path="/" exact component={RandomComponent} />
```

I get following warning in chrome console -

**Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`**

But When I export my component using

```
export class RandomComponent{ // component code}
```

same piece of code starts working, can someone explain me why this is happening? thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you importing RandomComponent

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [When should I use brackets with imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051886/when-should-i-use-brackets-with-imports/42051990#42051990)

Answer (score 0):

You most probably tried to import your component with curly braces even though it is a default export.

---

**DEFAULT EXPORT:**

If you use export your component with `default` specified (default export), you need to import it without curly braces like this:

```
import RandomComponent from '../pathToComponent';
```

---

**NAMED EXPORT:**

But if you export your component without `default` specified (named export), you need to import it with curly braces like this:

```
import { RandomComponent } from '../pathToComponent';
```

---

Do note that you can only have one default export from a single file but as many named exports as you want from a single file.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component of type object supplied to Route, expected  function

the  passed prop is not a component but is an object. your class should extend `React.Component`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class RandomComponent extends Component {/*your code*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6471#issuecomment-438292209) in `react-router` prior to version 4.4.

At the time of writing the latest version is 5.2, and using that version fixed the issue for me:

```sh
npm install --save react-router@latest
```

If you're using `react-router-dom` you may also want to update that.

Be aware that if you are having this problem your `react-router` is at least 2 major versions out of date; and there may be significant work required to get your routes to work in the latest version. Update packages across major version boundaries cautiously.